# How to add a string to Ajax Response in success function? JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a string to Ajax response in a selector.

```
function get_class_subject(class_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/get_class_subject/' + class_id,
    success: function(response) {
      jQuery('#subject_selector_holder').html(response);
      console.log('my message' + response);                
    }
  });
}
```

I am getting response as follows:

```html
my message<option value="5">Moral Science</option>
```

What I need to get is adding `<option value="100">Break</option>` that is

```html
my message<option value="5">Moral Science</option><option value="100">Break</option>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try using string concatenation?

Comment: Just append the HTML string, in the exact same way you already are in the `console.log`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
jQuery('#subject_selector_holder').html(response + '<option value="100">Break</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

just use )

```
console.log('my message' + response + "<option value="100">Break</option>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string conat

```
'my message' + response + '<option value="100">Break</option>'
```

or template strings

```
`my message${response}<option value="100">Break</option>`
```